# How to separate array elements into strings properly?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array set up like

```
%w(Dog Cat Bird Rat).each_with_index do |element, index|
# "w" for word array
# It's a shortcut for arrays

  puts ("%-4s + #{index}" % element)    
end
```

This will output something similar like

```
Dog + 0
Cat + 1
Bird + 2
Rat + 3
```

What if I want to change the animals to something such as a string?
So that it says

```
This is string 0 + 0
This is string 1 + 1
This is string 2 + 2
etc
```

Is there a way to do that?
This does not work:

```
%w('This is string 0', 'This is string 1', 'This is string 2', 'This is string 3').each_with_index do |element, index|
# "w" for word array
# It's a shortcut for arrays

  puts ("%-4s + #{index}" % element)    
end
```

Comment: `4.times { |i| puts "This is string #{i} + #{i}" }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the *"normal"* array syntax:

```
['This is string 0', 'This is string 1', 'This is string 2', 'This is string 3'].each_with_index do |element, index|
  puts ("%-4s + #{index}" % element)    
end

This is string 0 + 0
This is string 1 + 1
This is string 2 + 2
This is string 3 + 3
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want that your arrays can contain strings with spaces build it in the regular way.

```
['This is string 0', 'This is string 1', 'This is string 2', 'This is string 3'].each_with_index do |element, index|
```

Note that this could be written in many ways. One shorter way is

```
(0..3).map { |i| "This is string #{i}" }.each_with_index do |element, index|
```